# I've moved to an SSL and now my popup menu doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've moved to an SSL and now my popup menu on the nav doesn't work. It did work before hand. I can't see why it's not working. I didn't do anything to the CSS or javascript code.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  // Mobile menu toggle
  $('.fa-reorder').click(function(){
    $('body>nav ul').slideToggle();
  });
  //Checkboxes customization
  $(':checkbox').click(function(e){
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) $(this).addClass('checked');
    else $(this).removeClass('checked');
  });
  //landing page popups
  $('#signup').click(function(){
    $('#signup-popup, #cover').show();
    $('#cover, .fa-times').click(function(){
      $('#cover, #signup-popup').hide();
    });
  });
  $('#login').click(function(){
    $('#login-popup, #cover').show();
    $('#cover, .fa-times').click(function(){
      $('#cover, #login-popup').hide();
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <i class="fa fa-reorder"></i>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="https://www.serviceposts.com">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www.serviceposts.com/site/postings">POSTS</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www.serviceposts.com/site/about/hspw.php">HOW IT     WORKS</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www.serviceposts.com/site/about">ABOUT</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www.serviceposts.com/site/about/emailcsb.php">CONTACT</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="buttons">
    <input type="button" class="button green" value="SIGN UP" id="signup">
    <input type="button" class="button" value="LOGIN" id="login">
  </div>
  <div id="signup-popup">
    <h3>LET'S GET STARTED <i class="fa fa-times"></i></h3>
    <div class="part">
      <figure>
        <a     href="https://www.serviceposts.com/site/management/cust_reg.php"><img     src="images/SP_Signup_03.png" alt=""/></a>
      </figure>
      <input type="button" class="button green" value="I am a Consumer">
      <p><a href="https://www.serviceposts.com/site/management/cust_reg.php" class="blue">Make My Service Match Today</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="part">
      <figure>
        <a href="https://www.serviceposts.com/site/management/bus_reg.php"><img src="images/SP_Signup_05.png" alt=""/></a>
      </figure>
      <a href="https://www.serviceposts.com/site/management/bus_reg.php"><input type="button" class="button orange" value="I am a Service Provider"></a>
      <p><a href="https://www.serviceposts.com/site/management/bus_reg.php" class="blue">Make My Service Match Today</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="login-popup">
    <h3>LOGIN<i class="fa fa-times"></i></h3>
    <form action="https://www.serviceposts.com/site/welcome.php"     method="post">
      <label for="username1">Username</label>
      <input type="text" id="username1" name="uname"/>
      <label for="password1">Password</label>
      <input type="password" id="password1" name="txtpassword"/>
      <input type="submit" class="button green" value="LOGIN"/>
    </form>
    <a href="#">Forgot username or password?</a>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Is there a good tokenizer for javascript/css/html?

Comment: Does your css import other css from `http://` instead of `https://`?

Comment: Chances are the issue is somewhere else (header?).  Link working/broken version?

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is adding a redirect from http to https (web server will redirect all clients requests to https, if we forget change protocol in your app configuration):

Apache exemple:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    Redirect "/" "https://www.example.com/"
</VirtualHost >

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.example.com
    # ... SSL configuration goes here
</VirtualHost >
```

nginx exemple:

```
server {
  listen *:80;
  server_name example.com;
  proxy_set_header Host example.com;
  location / {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ https://example.com$1 permanent;
  }
}
server {
  listen *:443 ssl;
  server_name example.com;
  proxy_set_header Host example.com;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is mostly a cashing issue, or URL-rewrite issue.
If you are using a framework such as WordPress then this is a URL issue, since the links are stored in database, all you need to do is change main URL to be with https.

If not, then you got a caching issue, just purge cache and refresh your page.

Please note that if you purchase an CDN with your SSL that you disable the auto-minify option.0

Comment: it functions when it's http but not https. I like that CDN idea. I'm on the phone with the hosting company. They did say that cdn is part of the ssl bundle. They find it weird that javascripts seem to only function on http and not https. So they are currently chasing this. You guys are awesome! Update: CDN/SSL is blocking my javascript for some weird reason. They are chasing it.